# MST with special conditions

Tags: algorithm, optimization, tree, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I Need your help. I need to solve this task at my job to make calculation process easier.

Problem:

- I have a tree.  G(V,E); V = {v1, v2, ... , vn}; v1 is the root;
- Each node has properties P[v] - distributed pressure to v node and Q[v] - minimum pressure required to be distributed in v node.
- Each edge E(w, v) has property: EdgeType;
- Each EdgeType has properties loss(w, v) - percentage loss of pressure when distributing from w to v (Ex: if in P[w] node pressure is 1 and loss(w, v) = 20 then P[v] = 0.8), cost(w, v) cost of using this edge for pressure distribution;
- I have a set of EdgeTypes and P[v1] = 3; number of edgeTypes are less than 15;

My task is to choose EdgeTypes for each edges such that in all nodes I must have more or equal pressure than  required and cost should be minimal. 
I have not written any code yet, because only way I can solve this is brute force.

Comment: Does value of `loss(w, v)` depend on `w` and `v`? Is it also limited as `0 <= loss(w, v) <= 100` ?

Comment: loss(w,v) depends on edge type, Yes it is limited 0 < loss(w, y) < 100

Comment: Looks to me this can be formulated as a MIP (Mixed Integer Programming) problem.

Comment: How many vertices at most do you have?

Comment: Actually vertices are houses in a region. I think in this case 2000 is maximum

Comment: Could you also estimate what is the height of the tree at most?

Comment: I have never seen that tree height is more than 50.
theoretically more  is possible but I have never seen it before

Comment: Do edges have length? If yes should cost/loss then depend on length?

Comment: Yes those edges are gas pipes. it has length and diameter. the length is defined I cant change it. my task is to choose diameter for each pipe.
Higher is diameter smaller is loss. but higher diameter pipes has higher prices.

Comment: In such a case you have loss/cost values per meter of a pipe. Say you have 2 edges `a-b` and `x-y`. You may take a cheaper pipe type for `a-b` edge, but say `a-b` length is 10km while `x-y` is 1km, so overall cost may happen to be the same.

Comment: I understand, but lets consider that all pipes has the same length.  then I will be able to spread algorithm for different lengthes.

Comment: If you're prepared to discretise either the costs, or the pressures, into m different levels, then this can be solved in O(nm^2) time with dynamic programming, after first transforming the tree into a structurally related binary tree (if it's not already binary).  Basically, go through the vertices in postorder, and for each node v, and each pressure level p, compute the lowest cost f(v, p) of choosing edge types in the subtree rooted at v that satisfies the pressure requirements of all nodes in this subtree.  (You can take the negative logs of pressures to simplify the calculations a bit.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker, why is the tree needed to be binary? For each state of current vertex for every edge you will choose the edgeType giving minimum cost of the sum of edgeType cost and the cost of the subtree. So the cost of the state will be the sum of minimums by every edge. Also overall complexity might be O(n * m * nEdgeTypes)

Comment: @IvanGritsenko: You're right -- if we make the pressure the state at each node, we don't need to make the tree binary first.  I had originally thought of using costs as state variables, and then you need to try all possible ways of allocating the fixed "budget" at the current node among all its children, and there are O(m^k) ways of doing this for k children splitting a total budget of m.